# Tailwind CSS "file:" modifer is not working

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

I'm trying to style a file input in my Laravel project, but I am unable to style the button. I understand this should be possible as per the Tailwind docs (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#file-input-buttons) but when I try to replicate this any styles with the "file:" modifier just don't apply.

```
<label class="w-4/12 py-1 m-1 text-sm text-gray-700 font-bold text-right" for="file_input">Upload file</label>

<input class="file:bg-red-500 bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-purple-700 border border-gray-300" id="file_input" type="file" wire:model="csv" >
```

This ends up with the normal default button being applied without it getting a red background. The "hover:" modifer works as do all other styles.

[image]

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Works as expected in [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zagmdNS8hL) on newest version and chrome 114. What tailwind version do you use? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome browser, whatever the current version, and I updated to Tailwind 3.3.2 but still having the issue.

Comment: Tailwind play works, so the bug is probably somewhere else. Share your config, any steps to reproduce the problem, because as you can see, quite unreplicable with current information.

Answer (score -1):

It's likely to be an issue within your config. I had a similar issue and found out that a plugin within my tailwind config was actually conflicting with the file modifier for whatever reason. As soon as I set my plugin array to an empty array it worked.
The given plugin was serving a purpose so it's 1 step forward and 1 step back but investigating the config file is where I'd advise to start for anyone who would comes across this issue. Hope it helps.